# Mudar a posição ancora do seletor top do css?

Tags: html, css3

Olhá, estou tendo um problema na definição de um design web.
meu problema consistem um fazer uma `<div>` que está sendo usada para desenhar um linha transversal em uma pagina "html".
Porém quando eu uso a `-webkit-transform: skewY(10deg)` a posição margin-top fica centralizada no meio da `<div>` e assim essa `<div>` acaba perdendo parte de seu tamanho pois fica fora da pagina!
alguém saberia se existe alguma forma de mudar o ponto de ancora da margin-top para uma das laterais, ao invés de ficar centralizada?

Assim que ela teria que ficar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

mas ela fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
$(window).load(function(){
  $('.listra-fina-frente-1').css({'width':'42%', 'top':'44%', 'left':'0%', '-webkit-transition':'1s'});
    });
```

```css
.listra-fina-frente-1{
 position: absolute;
 top: 52%;
 left: 42%;
 height: 0.64935064935064935064935064935065%;
 width: 0;
 background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
 transform: skewY(10deg);
 -ms-transform: skewY(10deg);
 -webkit-transform: skewY(10deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
  <div class="listras-frente listra-fina-frente-1"></div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seria isso? eu nao entendi muito sua duvida. Como só esta com o `width` de `42%`, a linha não vai ate o final, mas acho que sua ideia deve ser essa mesma.

```js
$(window).load(function(){
  $('.listra-fina-frente-1').css({'width':'42%', 'top':'44%', 'right':'0%', '-webkit-transition':'1s'});
    });
```

```css
.listra-fina-frente-1{
 position: absolute;
 top: 52%;
 height: 0.64935064935064935064935064935065%;
 width: 0;
 background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
 transform: skewY(10deg);
 -ms-transform: skewY(10deg);
 -webkit-transform: skewY(10deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
  <div class="listras-frente listra-fina-frente-1"></div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Sim a linha tem que ter esse tamanho mesmo, porém na pagina html quando a linha é criada, por causa da proximidade com o top, parte dela some ultrapassando o top do navegador.